# Why Razor doesn't see included namespace?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces, include

Now I have next and it works

```
@foreach (TestLogs.Repository.DatabaseModel.Platforms CurrentPlatform in     Model.ApplicationPlatforms)
    {
...
    }
```

I want to include TestLogs.Repository.DatabaseModel namespace to Razor's view. I open web.config at views folder and add line there

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="TestLogs.Repository.DatabaseModel" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

But after that next construction doesn't work

```
 @foreach (Platforms CurrentPlatform in Model.ApplicationPlatforms)
    {
...
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you just have `@using TestLogs.Repository.DatabaseMoodel` at the top of the view instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my stupid question. It works but my Visual Studio 2012 doesn't mark class name with cyan color as it usually does.

[image: My VS2012 ScreenCapture]
<sub>(source: [piccy.info](http://i.piccy.info/i7/7f90d48e82726b44d1729b812ffd4874/4-55-2142/48623818/Result.jpg))</sub>